# How to add custom starting directory in WSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
[dawidn:/mnt/c/Users/dawin]$
```

This is my default shell directory, all of my projects are on partition d. Is there a way to make my shell start at a certain folder by default?

Comment: Try usermod -d /mnt/d.... dawidn

Comment: @RamanSailopal it doesn't work, this is the error I'm getting: usermod: user dawidn is currently used by process 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file ~/.bashrc

At the end of the file add the line:

```
cd /mnt/d/.....
```

Save an close the file.

On logging back into bash, you should have the specified directory as your initial current working directory.

Comment: It worked, but I have zsh installed, so instead of changing .bashrc, I've changed .zshrc.